# Can ROM be called SAM(Sequential Access Memory)?

Tags: memory, ram, cpu-cache, computation-theory, rom

ROM and RAM are 2 distinct memories, while RAM is randomly accessed, SAM is sequentially accessed, I understand that ROM is read-only but still, could it be said that a computer accesses it in a sequential manner(since it does not access it in a random manner) and hence it is a type of SAM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memory-access-methods/
[image: img from the article]

The second point clearly states that RAM and ROM are both applications of Random Access, and hence:
***NO, It CANNOT BE CALLED SAM as it an application of Random Access*** *and **NOT Sequential Access**.*